# getting lvalue and rvalue of a declaration

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Im parsing C++ with ANTLR4 grammar, I have a visitor function for `visitDeclarationStatement`. In the C++ code that Im trying to parse `Person p;` or a declaration of any custom type, in the tree I get two similar nodes and I cannot differentiate between the Lvalue and Rvalue!

```
"declarationStatement": [
{
  "blockDeclaration": [
  {
    "simpleDeclaration": [
    {
      "declSpecifierSeq": [
      {
        "declSpecifier": [
        {
          "typeSpecifier": [
          {
            "trailingTypeSpecifier": [
            {
              "simpleTypeSpecifier": [
              {
                "theTypeName": [
                {
                  "className": [
                  {
                    "type": 128,
                    "text": "Person"
                  }
                  ]
                }
                ]
              }
              ]
            }
            ]
          }
          ]
        }
        ]
      },
      {
        "declSpecifier": [
        {
          "typeSpecifier": [
          {
            "trailingTypeSpecifier": [
            {
              "simpleTypeSpecifier": [
              {
                "theTypeName": [
                {
                  "className": [
                  {
                    "type": 128,
                    "text": "p"
                  }
                  ]
                }
                ]
              }
              ]
            }
            ]
          }
          ]
        }
        ]
      }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": 124,
      "text": ";"
    }
    ]
  }
```

I want to be able to get Variable Type and Variable Name separately. What is the right way of doing that? How can I change the g4 file to get those results in a way that I can differentiate between the type and the name?

Thanks

Comment: L- and R-value of a declaration? I know what L- and R-value of an assignment is (i.e., Denotational Semantics, Stoy, '77, p282), but never heard it used this way, in the context of a decl statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to change the grammar. In case of `Person p;`, which is matched by:

```
declSpecifierSeq: declSpecifier+ attributeSpecifierSeq?;
```

the first child of `declSpecifierSeq` (which is `declSpecifier+`) will be a `List` of declSpecifier-contexts, of which the first is the type and the second the name.